# I am sufferring JAVA G1 issue

Tags: garbage-collection, call, system, g1gc

does any one encounter this kind of issue in java G1 gc

the first highlight user time is about 4 ms
but the second one user time is 0 ms and system time is about 4ms.

in G1 gc system time shouldn't be high, is it a bug in G1 gc?

### below is my gc argunments

```
Xms200g -Xmx200g -Xmn30g -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=5000 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC

2018-01-07T04:54:39.995+0800: 906650.864: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-01-07T04:54:39.996+0800: 906650.865: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 1610612736 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:   69747632 bytes,   69747632 total
- age   2:    9641544 bytes,   79389176 total
- age   3:   10522192 bytes,   89911368 total
- age   4:   11732392 bytes,  101643760 total
- age   5:    9158960 bytes,  110802720 total
- age   6:   10917528 bytes,  121720248 total
: 25341731K->170431K(28311552K), 0.2088528 secs] 153045380K->127882325K(206569472K), 0.2094236 secs] [Times: **user=4.53 sys=0.00, real=0.21 secs]**
Heap after GC invocations=32432 (full 10):
 par new generation   total 28311552K, used 170431K [0x00007f6058000000, 0x00007f67d8000000, 0x00007f67d8000000)
  eden space 25165824K,   0% used [0x00007f6058000000, 0x00007f6058000000, 0x00007f6658000000)
  from space 3145728K,   5% used [0x00007f6658000000, 0x00007f666266ffe0, 0x00007f6718000000)
  to   space 3145728K,   0% used [0x00007f6718000000, 0x00007f6718000000, 0x00007f67d8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 178257920K, used 127711893K [0x00007f67d8000000, 0x00007f9258000000, 0x00007f9258000000)
 Metaspace       used 54995K, capacity 55688K, committed 56028K, reserved 57344K
}
2018-01-07T04:54:40.205+0800: 906651.074: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2269738 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001692 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=32432 (full 10):
 par new generation   total 28311552K, used 25336255K [0x00007f6058000000, 0x00007f67d8000000, 0x00007f67d8000000)
  eden space 25165824K, 100% used [0x00007f6058000000, 0x00007f6658000000, 0x00007f6658000000)
  from space 3145728K,   5% used [0x00007f6658000000, 0x00007f666266ffe0, 0x00007f6718000000)
  to   space 3145728K,   0% used [0x00007f6718000000, 0x00007f6718000000, 0x00007f67d8000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 178257920K, used 127711893K [0x00007f67d8000000, 0x00007f9258000000, 0x00007f9258000000)
 Metaspace       used 54995K, capacity 55688K, committed 56028K, reserved 57344K
2018-01-07T04:55:02.541+0800: 906673.411: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-01-07T04:55:02.542+0800: 906673.411: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 1610612736 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:   93841912 bytes,   93841912 total
- age   2:   11310104 bytes,  105152016 total
- age   3:    8967160 bytes,  114119176 total
- age   4:   10278920 bytes,  124398096 total
- age   5:   11626160 bytes,  136024256 total
- age   6:    9077432 bytes,  145101688 total
: 25336255K->195827K(28311552K), 0.1926783 secs] 153048149K->127918291K(206569472K), 0.1932366 secs] [Times: **user=0.00 sys=4.07, real=0.20 secs]**
Heap after GC invocations=32433 (full 10):
 par new generation   total 28311552K, used 195827K [0x00007f6058000000, 0x00007f67d8000000, 0x00007f67d8000000)
  eden space 25165824K,   0% used [0x00007f6058000000, 0x00007f6058000000, 0x00007f6658000000)
  from space 3145728K,   6% used [0x00007f6718000000, 0x00007f6723f3cf38, 0x00007f67d8000000)
  to   space 3145728K,   0% used [0x00007f6658000000, 0x00007f6658000000, 0x00007f6718000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 178257920K, used 127722463K [0x00007f67d8000000, 0x00007f9258000000, 0x00007f9258000000)
 Metaspace       used 54995K, capacity 55688K, committed 56028K, reserved 57344K
}
2018-01-07T04:55:02.735+0800: 906673.604: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2149603 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002262 seconds
2018-01-07T04:55:14.673+0800: 906685.542: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0183883 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002046 seconds
2018-01-07T04:55:14.797+0800: 906685.666: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0135349 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002472 seconds
2018-01-07T04:55:14.810+0800: 906685.679: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0129019 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001014 seconds
2018-01-07T04:55:14.823+0800: 906685.692: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0125939 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002915 seconds
2018-01-07T04:55:21.597+0800: 906692.466: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0137018 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001683 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=32433 (full 10):
```

Comment: On which ground do you claim that “in G1 gc system time shouldn't be high”? How much do you know about it (considering that you did not even recognize that you are not using G1)?

Answer (score 0):

your command-line specifies `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` - this isn't a G1 issue.